# separating php from html?

Tags: php, html

I have PHP code with HTML inline, yet I need them to be separate on two pages. A HTML page with a form and a PHP form with the process on it.

The bits with the PHP form verification I need on a PHP page and the form I need on a HTML sheet the rest of the website will be on

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .error {color: #FF0000;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php // define variables and set to empty values
            $nameErr = $emailErr = "";
            $name = $email = "";
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                if(empty($_POST["name"])) {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
                else{$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);}
                if(empty($_POST["email"])) {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
                else{$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);}
            }
            function test_input($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
            }
        ?>
        <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
        <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
            <br><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
        </form>
        <?php
            echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
            echo $name;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $email;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

updated HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php require 'php.php'; echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php require 'php.php'; echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php require 'php.php'; echo $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay.  And what's stopping you?  What have you tried and what problem have you encountered?  What's your question?  Have you tried using an editor of some kind and creating your two files?

Comment: There is no html form in your code by the way.

Comment: let me add to my section the two pages i have and the errors thank you let me do that

Comment: mahanGN what form am i using then?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to put your php code in an other file (for example form.php). In your html file you need to include your php script. If your php file is situated in the same directory as your html file, your include statement could look like this.

```
<?php include 'form.php';?>
```

I'd like to refer you to [W3schools php include](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) where they explain in detail how you can link your php file.

Comment: i have edited my code and it saying errors on the above edit?

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving you a basic example to separate form file and php file. 
create a index.php file and write those code there

```
    <form action="post.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="txtName"/>
       <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit"/>

    </form>
```

Then create a post.php file and put below code there

```
      <?php

          if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){
            $val = $_POST['txtName'];
            echo $val;
          }

       ?>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: i get this but how can put that form on a website that is all html ? so the form would need to be on the html bit?

Comment: i am not clear actually . you want that form in "index.html" file and show php message in the php file. is that what you want ?

Comment: i kinda need to show the errors in the html dont i ?

Comment: okay to do that u will need jquery or javascript .
you can use jquery which will send data tho php page through ajax function

Comment: i dont know any of that can you find a website of a tutorial ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7Sn-f36TGM<br>

https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/simple-php-ajax-form-validation-example-from-scratchexample.html<br>
check this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

So here you have all the code for html form in your file. Now create a new file for process the form like "**process.php**" and post your form on that file. place this new file on the same directory where the HTML file is being placed and give path of this file into your form action = " " like

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
```

and in the process.php page you can process you form as you are doing.

```
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

            $name  = $_POST["name"];         
            $email = $_POST["email"];
        }
```

Comment: ive got this but i need to get the errors for validation to post back onto html

Comment: you can do that by redirecting to the form page with parameter like 
    $message="Your message";                                                                         redirect('formpage.php?message='.$message);

Comment: and then create a div to show that message on your form page and place a check in that div like :   if($_GET['message']){ echo $_GET['message'];  }     it will show your message you can style that message containing div as you like.

Comment: ill have a try mate